# TextBox.Text value not updating when being set

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Problem: 
DecimalTextBox has value set to "" after the line of code `txtSickTime.Text = newTest.PutThisDecimalInTheBox.ToString();`

The variable `txtSickTime.Text = newTest.PutThisDecimalInTheBox.ToString();` has it's value shown in visual studio as 320.5, So shouldn't this when converted to a string be able to be put in the DecimalTextBox without error?

Frontend

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MegA="clr-namespace:MegA;assembly=MegA" x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <MegA:DecimalTextBox DollarPrecision="12" Height="22.864" Name="txtSickTime" Width="60.00" MaxLength="4" TabIndex="230" DecimalPrecision="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Backend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication14
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Test newTest = new Test();
            txtSickTime.Text = newTest.PutThisDecimalInTheBox.ToString();
        }   
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public Decimal PutThisDecimalInTheBox;
        public Test()
        {
            PutThisDecimalInTheBox = 320.500m;
        }
    }
    public class DecimalTextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    {//this is a modified textbox that takes in decimal values also modified to highlight all text on focus
        bool alreadyFocused;
        private string PreviousText;
        string _filterString;
        int _dollarPrecision;
        int _decimalPrecision;
        public string FilterString
        {
            get { return _filterString; }
            set { _filterString = value; }
        }

        public int DollarPrecision
        {
            get { return _dollarPrecision; }
            set { _dollarPrecision = value; }
        }

        public int DecimalPrecision
        {
            get { return _decimalPrecision; }
            set { _decimalPrecision = value; }
        }
        public decimal TextDecimal
        {
            get { return Convert.ToDecimal(this.Text); }
        }


        public DecimalTextBox()
        {
            TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right;
            FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Courier New");
            FilterString = "-1234567890.";
            this.TextChanged += DecimalTextBox_TextChanged;//add the events
        }
        //event function that limits the input in the text box
        private void DecimalTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.TextChanged -= DecimalTextBox_TextChanged;//remove the event so it doesn't get called again
            //get the cursor location to fix it later
            int location = this.SelectionStart;
            //don't allow anything except the filter string
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterString)))
            {
                if (this.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= this.Text.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (!(this.FilterString.Contains(this.Text.Substring(i, 1))))
                        {
                            this.Text = this.Text.Remove(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                string tempText = Text.Replace("-", "");
                string[] splitAtDecimal = tempText.Split('.');
                if (splitAtDecimal.Length > 2)
                {
                    Text = PreviousText;
                }
                else if (splitAtDecimal.Length == 2)
                {
                    if (splitAtDecimal[0].Length > DollarPrecision)//if violating dollar or decimal precision return to previoustext
                    {
                        Text = PreviousText;
                    }
                    if (splitAtDecimal[1].Length > DecimalPrecision)
                    {
                        Text = PreviousText;
                    }
                }
                //set the PreviousText=Text for comparison next time textchanged is called
                PreviousText = Text;
                //this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
                this.TextChanged += DecimalTextBox_TextChanged;//add the event back
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer the question. I will say this: your code would be a lot easier to write in the long run if you'd learn the intended idioms for WPF. You should be using data binding instead of setting control values directly, and you shouldn't need to subclass `TextBox` to get this to work. Using a converter for binding and validation rules for validating input will give a much better experience. Seems like spending some time researching those topics would be a productive use of your time.

Comment: I find it very hard to recreate the problem since I am at a loss as to what it is.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @PeterDuniho. If you are using WPF, your code-behind should be limited to ViewModel population and other business rules that can't be handled by WPF itself. But, displaying values should be done with data bindings, and values can be used with converters to do any number of things (data type to another, changing control attributes, etc).

Comment: Also, how is it hard to recreate the problem since your the one posting it? You should at least have the XAML for the form or whatever that you're trying to work with.

Comment: Alright hold on here there are like, 34,000 lines of code. Splitting it in to it's simplest form might take me a bit.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to recreate the problem, because when the data came from the database it was immediately turned in to a decimal. I did not know trailing zeros were retained after being converted to the decimal. It just didn't make sense to me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the problem is occurring is because although visual studio displays the value of the decimal as 320.5, when it is converted to a string it retains those 2 trailing zeros.

Thus your string will be 320.500.

The answer to the question in this case would be to either drop the trailing zeros or add +1 to your DecimalTextBox's DecimalPrecision, otherwise it gets reverted to the DecimalTextBox's original value of "".

Personally I believe it should show the trailing zeros if it's going to retain them after the fact.